# About what does FunctionSurjective think so long time?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Having tried a new in 12.2 command `FunctionSerjective`, I executed

```
FunctionSurjective[z^(5/2), z, Complexes] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{903.926, True}`

and

```
FunctionSurjective[z^(5/4), z, Complexes] // AbsoluteTiming
```

However, the latter was running without any responce on my comp during
approximately *12 hours*. After that I terminated it though the resouces (the RAM and processor)
were not exhausted.

How to explain this difference?
The outputs of

```
Reduce[z^(5/2) == w, z, Complexes]
```

> `(w == 0 && z == 0) || (w != 0 && z == w^(2/5)) || (w != 0 &&  0 == -Sqrt[(-1)^(2/5) w^(2/5)] - (-1)^(1/5) w^(1/5) &&  z == (-1)^(2/5) w^(2/5)) || (w != 0 &&  0 == -Sqrt[(-1)^(4/5) w^(2/5)] + (-1)^(2/5) w^(1/5) &&  z == (-1)^(4/5) w^(2/5)) || (w != 0 &&  0 == -Sqrt[-(-1)^(1/5) w^(2/5)] - (-1)^(3/5) w^(1/5) &&  z == -(-1)^(1/5) w^(2/5)) || (w != 0 &&  0 == -Sqrt[-(-1)^(3/5) w^(2/5)] + (-1)^(4/5) w^(1/5) &&  z == -(-1)^(3/5) w^(2/5))`

and

```
Reduce[z^(5/4) == w, z, Complexes]
```

> `(w == 0 && z == 0) || (w != 0 && z == w^(4/5)) || (w != 0 &&  0 == -((-1)^(4/5) w^(4/5))^(1/4) - (-1)^(1/5) w^(1/5) &&  z == (-1)^(4/5) w^(4/5)) || (w != 0 &&  0 == -(-(-1)^(3/5) w^(4/5))^(1/4) + (-1)^(2/5) w^(1/5) &&  z == -(-1)^(3/5) w^(4/5)) || (w != 0 &&  0 == -((-1)^(2/5) w^(4/5))^(1/4) - (-1)^(3/5) w^(1/5) &&  z == (-1)^(2/5) w^(4/5)) || (w != 0 &&  0 == -(-(-1)^(1/5) w^(4/5))^(1/4) + (-1)^(4/5) w^(1/5) &&  z == -(-1)^(1/5) w^(4/5))`

are similar. Also $ z^{\frac 5 2}$ maps $\{re^{i\phi}:r\ge 0,\phi>-\pi,\phi\le \pi\}$ onto
its superset $\{r^{\frac 5 2}e^{i \frac 5 2 \phi}:r\ge 0,\phi>-\pi,\phi\le \pi\}$ and
$ z^{\frac 5 4}$ maps the complex plane onto its superset
$\{r^{\frac 5 4}e^{i \frac 5 4 \phi}:r\ge 0,\phi>-\pi,\phi\le \pi\}$.